# LotusNotes DateTime object and TimeZone property

Tags: datetime, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Domino server sitting in CET/CEDT.

An email on that server has a DeliveredDate, maybe in the same time zone, maybe not, but let's have it set to `2014-03-01 11:01:38 CET`.

Second thing I have is some "canonical time zone string" of another timezone, let's say `Z=-4$DO=0$...$ZN=Arabian`

**How can I get - in a LotusScript ServerTask - the DeliveredDate converted to the time zone represented by aforementioned time zone string?**

If some LotusScript servertask puts that date into a `NotesDateTime` object, I can get the properties `LSLocalTime`, which is CET, `LSGMTTime`, which is GMT, and `ZoneTime`, which of course also returns CET. Functions include `ConvertToZone`, which does not take a string, and the undocumented `merge`, which changes the time, such that 11:01 CET becomes 11:01 AST (8:01 CET).

But a delivered date of 2014-03-01 11:01 CET should become 2014-03-01 14:01 AST;
and a delivered date of 2014-04-01 11:01 CEDT should become 2014-04-01 13:01 AST.

How?

Comment: Where does that timezone string come from? What is the format? It's not something I've seen before. As far as I know, there's nothing in the LotusScript language or Domino objects for interpreting a string like that -- but if you explain more about it, someone here might be able to come up with some advice. BTW: a limitation of the ConvertToZone method is that it only takes Daylight Saving Time rules into account for the convert-from zone, not the converted-to zone, and that alone is a pretty significant problem.

Comment: The string (in so-called "canonical time zone format") is taken from a user profile.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting.  Seems to be an IBM invention. Documented here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21163045 I'm not aware of any functions in public APIs that support it, and even though it encodes DST info the limitation I mentioned above for ConvertToZone makes it not so useful. I was kind of hoping it would be a standards-based format that was supported in Java so you could call out via LS2J to some useful functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes formula language has a function that does exactly what you want.  It's called `@TimeToTextInZone`.  According to [this developerWorks thread](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/ecf166c9290bc6e98525792f003825e7?OpenDocument), there is no equivalent in LotusScript.  However, you could try using `NotesSession.Evaluate()` combined with `@TimeToTextInZone`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that string contains the values for the zone and dst arguments to ConvertToZone, so you can just parse it and use that method, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Andre, the canonical string tells you the base offset from UTC and gives you the law for observing DST (if applicable).  It doesn't immediately tell you whether DST is observed on the specific date.  For that you have to evaluate the DST law.  I think Alexander is trying to avoid that.